# Unauthorized access after creating user and assign role using [CustomAuthorize(Roles = "User")]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, authorization

I have created user and assign the role. Both tables AspNetUsers and AspNetUserRoles gets updated. Ideally here, user is authenticated and authrorized. But when I try to navigate, it throws UnAuthorized access error. If I logout and try to login again, it works perfect. This problem is only at the time of creation of user. I have added `[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "User")]` to the controller I am accessing.

Sample Code is :

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.EmailID, Email = model.EmailID, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName,Organisation = model.Organisation, isAdmin = model.isAdmin };
                var result1 = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result1.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "User");
                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
```

When I redirect to Home controller, the control comes into `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` function.

My custom authorize class is as follow:

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                    RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "AccessDenied" }));
            }
        }


    }
```

The controller code is as follows:

```
[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        MusicJournalContext db = new MusicJournalContext();
        private static RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Articles", new { status = "InProcess" });
            } else if(User.IsInRole("User")){
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "EndUser");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

I found 1 solution, but it was not working. I have added `await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);` Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead of you method. You were skipping role check, because of that your user was getting unauthorized.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
            else
            {
                var rolesArray = Roles.Split(',');
                var isAllowed = rolesArray.Any(role => filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(role));
                if (!isAllowed)
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                        RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "AccessDenied" }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting isAllowed as false so still getting AccessDenied. I checked User.IsInRole('User'), it is false. Do you have any idea why it is set to false? I can see 'User' in the rolesArray.

Comment: Got the solution bro. I was setting role after login. I just swapped the statements.                                                                                       await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "User"); 
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

Comment: @KFC perfect. I didn't see your register code first because i saw issue with your CustomAuthorize.